# Native script How do I access 10.0.2.2 android

Tags: android, localhost, ssl-certificate, nativescript

I am attempting to make the call

```
 async RetrieveReports() : Promise<any[]>
  {
    const response = await fetch("http://10.0.2.2:5001/weatherforecast");
  const body = await response.json();
  var reports = <string[]> body;
  return reports;
  }
```

This is hosted locally as a .net WebApi and
Using localhost worked fine for angular. 
However when I try to use 10.0.2.2 for the android emulator I get

Network request failed: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 10.0.2.2 not permitted
even though my \App_Resources\Android\AndroidManifest.xml file 
has

```
<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

using https
I get

```
TypeError: Network request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I'm not sure how to get the cert working here?
Any ideas how to get rid of these errors?

Comment: Are you redirecting your requests to https on api side? Do you have any custom SSL certificate setup?

Comment: What you can see in debug mode, Chrome debugger Networks tab? Maybe that'd help to find out what's going on. If it worked on localhost maybe it's a CORS issue. The second issue is about the https certification.

Comment: So going roughly based on https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/ and some various trial and error. I was able to get the emulator and localhost to connect, and the chrome browser in the emulator showed "secure". So I would normally think I was done, but the NativeScript app is still giving the error?? So I do have a self signed cert, which I have (I think?) installed on the android emulator, and chrome no longer warns and provides the API results via 10.0.2.2 I just can't get the same from the fetch.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No. I ended up figuring out the clear text path on angular, and moved to azure container instances (still a side-project /  non prod site).